# Is it possible to send a text message with a video attachment in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, sms

I was wonder if it was possible to send a text message with a video attachment using Swift?

Comment: Send it using what?

Comment: MFMessageComposeViewController or something

Comment: Yes it is possible. how depends on whether you are building a standard app or an iMessage app

Comment: Just a standard app. The idea is to record a video and send it to a bunch of phone numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way to do this is by using [`UIActivityViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiactivityviewcontroller). You can include the video in `activityItems` (FYI, it’s possible to add more items, like the video’s title, etc.). A standard share sheet will appear listing services compatible with `activityItems`. The user will be able to select the desired service: iMessage, email, and more.

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a closer look at that.